# How to take picture without freezing with tkinter and opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, webcam

I am fairly new to coding and Tkinter and very new to opencv. I am trying to code simple webcam app that can take snapshot every time I press a button. I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")

label =Label(root)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

def show_frames():
   cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
   label.imgtk = imgtk
   label.configure(image=imgtk)
   label.after(20, show_frames)

def key_pressed(event):
   take_pic()

def take_pic():
   cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
   ###Rest of the photo saving script

show_frames()
root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

In further version I am able to take as many pictures and save them as many times as I want, but in part of the GUI that has the picture seems to freeze after I take the first pic. Other than that the program seems to run. Other sideffect is that the every pic after the first is very dark. It seems that camera needs seccond or two to adjust the light level.

I have narrowed down that it is the `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` part, that messes things up, but I am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: You don't need to call `cv2.VideoCapture(...)` again inside `take_pic()`.  Add `global img` at the beginning of `show_frames()` and then you can simply call, for example, `img.save('screenshot.png')` inside `take_pic()` to save a capture image.  Actually you can call `img.save(...)` inside `key_pressed()` and then `take_pic()` can be removed.

Comment: This is elegant and working solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")

label = Label(root)
label.frame_num = 0
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

def show_frames():
   cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
   label.imgtk = imgtk
   label.frame_num += 1.
   label.configure(image=imgtk)
   label.after(20, show_frames)

def key_pressed(event):
   take_pic()

def take_pic():
    file_name = f"{label.frame_num}.png"
    imagetk = label.imgtk
    imgpil = ImageTk.getimage( imagetk )
    imgpil.save(file_name, "PNG")
    imgpil.close()


show_frames()
root.bind("p", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not sure why but this wont start the GUI at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the take_pic function, you are reassigning the cam with id "0" to another variable thus, the variable assigned to tkinter is getting blocked from accessing the camera.

Attaching the modifications below to store the images. I am storing each frame being shown in a global variable, and then as soon as the key is pressed, it is storing the image of this global variable.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")

label =Label(root)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cv2image = None

def show_frames():
    global cv2image
    cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
    label.imgtk = imgtk
    label.configure(image=imgtk)
    label.after(20, show_frames)

def key_pressed(event):
    take_pic()

i = 0
def take_pic():
    global i
    cv2.imwrite(f"pics/{i}.jpg", cv2image)
    i += 1
    ###Rest of the photo saving script

show_frames()
root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```